# Django Templating include with a js block

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

Imagine I have 3 templates with the same structure...

```
    {% block extra_css %}
        {# some html #}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        {# some html #}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block extra_js %}
        {# some html #}
    {% endblock %}
```

Somewhere in the content, I need to include a partial with a specific html. That partial needs a js script to work properly. Is it possible for me to somehow add that script to my partial in a way that meets these requirements?

1 - The html goes to the `content` block.

2 - The js goes to the `extra_js` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking to a friend of mine, he explained me it isn't possible to do it yet.

So, if I need to include that partial that needs a script to work properly, I need to manually include the script in the template each time I use the partial.